# An verb or expression for regularly writing about things that occur

Tags: verbs

I'm not a native english speaker.

I'm looking for a verb that expresses (regularly) writing about things or situations.

Two words came to mind; 
chronicling
novelling
logging

Any verb will do, as long as I can use it to describe me adding text to my work log.

Kind regards,

Comment: Since you call it a *log*  the verb should be *logging*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a verb that fits my request: Journaling. To journal.

Comment: Did you find it in a dictionary?

Comment: It just popped up in my mind. I found a reference at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/journal